# Spark SQL equivalent of SQL IN Condition

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

Im new on Spark, I need help on how I can use IN Condition in sparkSQL

SELECT
name,age
WHERE age IN (25,35,45)
FROM table

Comment: Your SQL syntax has a mistake - WHERE goes after FROM: `SELECT name,age FROM table WHERE age IN (25,35,45)` - does this solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

This should work `df.where(col('age').isin([25, 35, 45)).select('name', 'age')`

For reference, see the [spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.Column.isin.html)